# Banner displays perfectly in FF, not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I built a banner for a customer using HTML, CSS + JQuery. The website it is on is a PHP Laravel project, the initial developer (of the website) didn't implement the banner correctly and I was asked by the client to implement on its own standalone page on their site.

The link that leads to this goes to an `advert.blade.php` file (from `index.blade.php`) - initially I dropped the CSS, HTML and JS from my project into `advert.blade.php` - this works absolutely fine in FF, not in Chrome. Strangely though it does seem to work correctly when I inspect the page. I thought an easy workaround is just to add the original project folder into the public folder and link directly to the `banner.html` - this achieves the same results, works great in FF but not in Chrome, except this time Chromes console logs two errors - access to the CSS + JS files is denied by the client.

This works perfectly in my local version in both Chrome + FF. I have included links to both live versions at the bottom of this post.

Relevant code:

```js
var tap = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);

$adSlideOne = $('#ad-banner-slide-1');
$adSlideTwo = $('#ad-banner-slide-2');
$adCtaOne = $('#ad-banner-cta-1');
$adCtaTwo = $('#ad-banner-cta-2');

var adShowSlide = () => {
  var adOpt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

  return adOpt;
}

var adDisplay = adShowSlide();

if (adDisplay > 0) {
  $adSlideOne.show();
  $adCtaOne.hide();
} else {
  $adSlideTwo.show();
  $adCtaTwo.hide();
}

if (!tap) {
  $adSlideOne.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $adCtaOne.fadeIn(800);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $adCtaOne.fadeOut();
  })

  $adSlideTwo.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $adCtaTwo.fadeIn(800);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $adCtaTwo.fadeOut();
  })
}
```

```css
.ad-banner-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.ad-banner {
  height: 170px;
  width: 728px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  position: relative;
}

.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-slide-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-cta h1,
.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-cta h2 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-slide-content img {
    max-height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}

.ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ad-banner #ad-banner-slide-1 {
  background-image: url('http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/includes/imgs/handy-bg.jpeg');
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

.ad-banner #ad-banner-slide-1 p {
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: right;

}
.ad-banner #ad-banner-slide-2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/includes/imgs/tools-bg.jpg');
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;

  display: none;
}

.ad-banner #ad-banner-slide-2 .ad-banner-slide-content {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ad-banner #ad-banner-slide-2 #ad-banner-cta-2 h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Desktop || Mobile */
.ad-banner-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .ad-banner-desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  .ad-banner-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  .ad-banner .ad-banner-slide .ad-banner-slide-content {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .ad-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .ad-banner img {
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

/*
  BTNS CSS Library by Daniel Winning
*/

/* Font face */
/* Borders, sizing, transition and effects */
/* Button colours */
.btns-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transition: 0.5s; }

/* Standard buttons */
.btns-red {
  background-color: #eb4f40;
  border: 1px solid #eb4f40; }

.btns-blue {
  background-color: #407beb;
  border: 1px solid #407beb; }

.btns-green {
  background-color: #6ebe6e;
  border: 1px solid #6ebe6e; }

.btns-orange {
  background-color: #ec7a15;
  border: 1px solid #ec7a15; }

.btns-purple {
  background-color: #a05ebb;
  border: 1px solid #a05ebb; }

/* Standard Hovers */
.btns-red:hover {
  background-color: rgba(235, 79, 64, 0.75); }

.btns-blue:hover {
  background-color: rgba(64, 123, 235, 0.75); }

.btns-green:hover {
  background-color: rgba(110, 190, 110, 0.75); }

.btns-orange:hover {
  background-color: rgba(236, 122, 21, 0.75); }

.btns-purple:hover {
  background-color: rgba(160, 94, 187, 0.75); }

/* Single Borders */
/* Coloured bottom border */
.btns-red-bottom, .btns-blue-bottom, .btns-green-bottom, .btns-orange-bottom, .btns-purple-bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid; }

/* Coloured left border */
.btns-red-left, .btns-blue-left, .btns-green-left, .btns-orange-left, .btns-purple-left {
  border-left: 4px solid; }

.btns-red-bottom, .btns-red-left {
  border-color: #eb4f40; }

.btns-blue-bottom, .btns-blue-left {
  border-color: #407beb; }

.btns-green-bottom, .btns-green-left {
  border-color: #6ebe6e; }

.btns-orange-bottom, .btns-orange-left {
  border-color: #ec7a15; }

.btns-purple-bottom, .btns-purple-left {
  border-color: #a05ebb; }

/* Default hover effect */
.btns-red-bottom:hover, .btns-blue-bottom:hover, .btns-green-bottom:hover, .btns-purple-bottom:hover, .btns-orange-bottom:hover,
.btns-red-left:hover, .btns-blue-left:hover, .btns-green-left:hover, .btns-purple-left:hover, .btns-orange-left:hover {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.75); }

/* Alternate hover effects - coloured hover */
.btns-alt-red:hover {
  background-color: #eb4f40; }

.btns-alt-blue:hover {
  background-color: #407beb; }

.btns-alt-green:hover {
  background-color: #6ebe6e; }

.btns-alt-orange:hover {
  background-color: #ec7a15; }

.btns-alt-purple:hover {
  background-color: #a05ebb; }

/* Rounded buttons */
.btns-round {
  border-radius: 8px; }

/* Shadowed buttons */
.btns-shadow {
  box-shadow: 3px 8px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

/*# sourceMappingURL=btns.css.map */
```

```html
  <div class='ad-banner-container'>
    <div class='ad-banner'>
      <div class='ad-banner-slide' id='ad-banner-slide-1'>
        <div class='ad-banner-slide-content'>
          <img src='http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/includes/imgs/logo-alt.png'>
          <p>Whatever the job, we've got just the tools you need!</p>
          <a class='btns-button btns-red ad-banner-mobile'>Sign-up Now</a>
        </div>
        <div class='ad-banner-cta' id='ad-banner-cta-1'>
          <h1>Check out our brand new online store!</h1>
          <a class='btns-button btns-red' href='#'>Sign-up Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='ad-banner-slide' id='ad-banner-slide-2'>
        <div class='ad-banner-slide-content'>
          <img class='ad-banner-mobile' src='http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/includes/imgs/logo-alt.png'>
          <p>A tool for every job!</p>
          <img class='ad-banner-desktop' src='http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/includes/imgs/logo-alt.png'>
          <a class='btns-button btns-red ad-banner-mobile'>Shop Now!</a>
        </div>
        <div class='ad-banner-cta' id='ad-banner-cta-2'>
          <h2>Discover your next new tool on our new online store...</h2>
          <a class='btns-button btns-red' href='#'>Shop Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I apologise for the long post, hopefully I am clear in what I have asked and I have provided adequate explanation. My question is, why is this not working in Google Chrome in both live versions?

Edited to add: the links in the code above have been updated in order for the example in this post to run properly.

[PHP Blade](http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/advert)
[Banner Project](http://www.handymans-hardware.co.uk/ad-banner/banner.html)

Comment: Well for me it works fine in chrome and not at all in FF. But i have an ad-blocker in FF and not in Chrome. I assume the opposite holds true in your case, and your chrome ad-blocker removes the banners.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli that makes sense.. perhaps I need to go through and change all selectors to something that doesnt include "ad" or "advert".. that's annoying if that is the case, but your comment seems to shed light on this, thanks for the help.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli please add your comment as an answer and I will accept the answer - changing all of the CSS selectors and JS variable names to not include 'ad' solved my problem. I'm not sure if the variable names have any bearing, I changed them just in case.